# Compilation error: "Unexpected symbol ')', expected identifier

Tags: c#

I've wrote my first C# script, but I get this error: Compilation error: "Unexpected symbol ')', expected identifier

```
using System;

class MainClass {
    public static void Main() {
        int[] integers = new int[5];
        integers[0] = 4;
        integers[1] = 12;
        integers[2] = 68;
        integers[3] = 2;
        integers[4] = 8;

        Console.WriteLine(GetAverage(integers));
    }

    public static float GetAverage (array) {
        float average = 0;
        foreach (int num in array) {
            average += num;
        }
        average /= average.Lenght;

        return average;
    }
}
```

Could anyone explain to me why I get the error? Thanks.

Comment: Which line does the error refer to?

Comment: Firstly: it's great that you've given us the full code and the error message, but please always say *where* you're getting the error. I assume it's on `public static float GetAverage (array)`. You haven't specified a type for the `array` parameter. You probably want `int[] array`

Comment: Look at line number in error message. It should be GetAverage(Array array) for function definition. Do you use VisualStudio? Because it shouldn’t even compile, also length is misspelled.

Comment: @estinamir: "Because it shouldn’t even compile" - well yes, this is a compile-time error...

Comment: should read         public static float GetAverage(int[] array)....and  if you spell length correctly you will see that a float doesnt have a length property

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `GetAverage` method does not define a type for the `array` parameter.
2. You're calling a `Length` method (misspelled) on a `float`; I think you intended to call `array.Length` instead.

Finally, the error message should have a line number, but you're not showing us which line that is.

Comment: It works now.  (average.Lenght was misspelled) Thanks for the help.